# Add/Subtract from each parameter in variadic template and forward the result

Tags: templates, expression, c++14, c++17, variadic

Let's assume that I have a function which takes a variadic template of integers:

```
template < int... I > int dummy()
{
    // to each int in I add/subtract something
    // and forward the pack with modified values somewhere else
    // test< (I -/+ n)... >
}
```

And for each value in the parameter pack, I would like to perform a mathematical operation and forward the pack with the modified values to somewhere else.

For example to another type like this one:

```
template < int... I > struct test;

template < int _0 > struct test< _0 > {
    // use params...
};
template < int _1, int _0 > struct test< _1, _0 > {
    // use params...
};
template < int _2, int _1, int _0 > struct test< _2, _1, _0 > {
    // use params...
};
template < int _3, int _2, int _1, int _0 > struct test< _3, _2, _1, _0 > {
    // use params...
};
```

So that if the function is called like:

```
dummy< 1, 2, 3, 4>();
```

And I subtract 1 from each value in the parameter pack. It'll be equivalent to using `test` like:

```
test< 0, 1, 2, 3 >
```

This is not the scenario in which I need this but rather an example to illustrate what I mean.

I was looking tinto C++17 Fold expressions but from what I could understand it doesn't generate a modified parameter pack but rather folds them to a single value.

What is an efficient way with decent compile time of achieving this?

**EDIT**:

To give an example where I would use this. I would like to have a variadic user defined literal like:

```
template < char... I > int operator"" _test()
{
    //...
}
```

That I could call like:

```
18264_test;
```

But the received parameters are their ASCII decimals not the actual number.

So I would like to be able to have something like `(I - '0')...` which gives me the actual number.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: The user defined literal which takes a parameter pack of ASCII characters had to transform something like the ASCII character '2' (decimal 50) into the actual number 2. So I wanted to know how I could subtract the ASCII character '0' from each received character and forward the resulted parameter pack somewhere else.

The use case of this would be to form shuffle masks for SIMD intrinsics. Where I could replace the macro `_MM_SHUFFLE(1,2,3,4)` with a scoped constexpr user defined literal `1234_ShM`.

And later even with letters `XYYZ_ShLM`. Does this make the question clearer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had the answer all this time.

```
template < char C > int test()
{
    printf("%d_", C);
    return C;
}
template < char C1, char C2, char... Cs > int test()
{
    printf("%d_", C1);
    return C1 + test<C2, Cs...>();
}

template < char... I > int operator"" _show()
{
    return test< (I - '0')... >();
}
```

Comment: If I want to get the decimal value of `'1'`, then I would call `49_show;`, right. However, this will take `4` and `9` separately, which is not what you want. See my answer.

Comment: [Here's what I mean in action](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dXqG9oT64YLRrc4z). You can see that while `test` does receive integers, it is not converting our ASCII value of 49 (`a`) to `1` (decimal), rather than `4` and `9`. So you're forced to provide integers in the first place, which sort of defeats the purpose of conversion...

Comment: That was the actual goal. To get each character separately and then subtract the '0' which would give me the actual index. However, soon after posting this question I realized it wasn't a very flexible approach and that it required move validation than necessary.

This was what I was trying to achieve: https://github.com/iSLC/Literal-SIMD-Shuffle-Masks

The reason I initially kept SIMD out of the question was because I was trying to avoid making it look like a SIMD question but rather as a template manipulation question.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The code you've showed on GitHub is ill-formed: `template < typename CharT, CharT... Cs > constexpr int operator"" _Shuffle()`. If you provide a templated literal,  it must have an empty parameter list and can have only one template parameter, which must be a non-type template parameter pack with element type `char`. Also, usage like `"Yy1y"_Shuffle` is a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) which should look for a much different looking function. Either it's a compiler bug, or it's ill-formed no diagnostic required. It's not portable code.

Comment: Apparently that's a GCC extension (supported by clang as well). And only on C++14. Which for my needs, works just fine. Thanks for the info. Surprisingly though, on MinGW, it worked with C++11.

Comment: That makes sense. It appears to be "-Wgnu-string-literal-operator-template", and GCC/Clang fail if `-Wall -pedantic -Werror` are on. Please update your GitHub page to indicate it is non-standard C++, or alternatively do something like I have in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want to use a user-defined literal, because then you're kind of limiting yourself on the sorts of input it can take. Instead you could define a free floating function that performs the operation and passes it on to `test`:

```cpp
struct test
{
    static void apply()
    {
        std::cout << "test received integers ";
        (... , (std::cout << I << " "));
    }
};

template<int RHS, int... VALS>
constexpr auto SubtractAndForward()
{
    return test<(VALS - RHS)...>::apply();
}
int main()
{
    SubtractAndForward<1, 1, 2, 3>();
}
```

#### [Demo1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2YP9pQkhFOhnq0JA)

`test::apply` uses a [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to print

> test received integers 0 1 2

However, this feels awkward. Since you're always forwarding to `test`, why not encapsulate both operations in the same `struct`:

```cpp
struct test
{
    template<int RHS, int... VALS>
    static auto SubtractAndApply()
    {
        return apply<(VALS - RHS)...>();
    }

    template<int... I>
    static void apply()
    {
        std::cout << "test received integers ";
        (... , (std::cout << I << " "));
    }
};
```

#### [Demo2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pzsXTsmSFzkodgoN)

This still feels a bit awkward. Let's also parameterize the predicate we send, so we can do addition or subtraction:

```cpp
struct test
{
    template<template<class> class F, int RHS, int... VALS>
    static auto ComputeAndApply()
    {
        return apply<F<int>{}(VALS, RHS)...>();
    }

    template<int... I>
    static void apply()
    {
        std::cout << "test received integers ";
        (... , (std::cout << I << " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    test::ComputeAndApply<std::minus, 1, 1, 2, 3>();
    test::ComputeAndApply<std::plus, 1, 1, 2, 3>();
}
```

#### [Demo 3](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zeUZhzMlbGjoPyDg)

Output:

> test received integers 0 1 2 
>   test received integers 2 3 4